Why find command behaves this way?
Here is a terminal output:
paul@cube:~$ find / libhwinfo_cpu.so
...
/home/paul/hwinfo/build/lib/libhwinfo_cpu.so
...
find: ‘libhwinfo_cpu.so’: No such file or directory
paul@cube:~$ sudo find / -name  libhwinfo_cpu.so
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/paul/hwinfo/build/lib/libhwinfo_cpu.so

Why the first invocation of find claims that libhwinfo_cpu.so doesn't exist?

In the first invocation, you specify both / and libhwinfo_cpu.so as paths to search within. The latter path is relative, so it really means "search within ~/libhwinfo_cpu.so", which indeed doesn't exist.
In the second invocation you add -name, so you're specifying only / as the path to search within and -name libhwinfo_cpu.so as the condition to search for. Since it's no longer a path but only a name to compare against, there's no error message.

But the first invocation listed all paths it searched, including /home/paul/hwinfo/build/lib/libhwinfo_cpu.so. It doesn't look like it was searching only within ~/libhwinfo_cpu.so.

@PaulJurczak You did specify /. The file /home/paul/hwinfo/build/lib/libhwinfo_cpu.so is under /.
